# Flutter Navigator.Push choppy and shows slight after-image

Tags: flutter

I'm experiencing some annoying weird white flashes when I use the built in Navigator to push a new screen as seen in the below gif.

[image]

I'm having problems throughout my app with similar issues of the previous screen staying for half a second kind of like an after image while the new screen is animated on top which makes the experience very unpleasant. This happens even on release mode. Can anyone help me ensure that the transitions are smooth?

Build method for the screen that pushes the second screen:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Title'),),
        body: Card(
            child: ListTile(
                leading: Icon(Icons.info),
                title: Text(
                    'Go to screen 2',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25),
                ),
                onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
                        return AboutScreen();
                    }));
                },
            ),
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: if you are running in debug performances are slower than in release mode `flutter run --release`

Comment: Yes as I mentioned in the post this happens even in release mode.

Comment: oh, sorry, do you experience that on real device as well?

Comment: Yes on my samsung phone i experience it. My only hunch is it has something to do with the ListTile, since I tried it with an animation of 0 seconds and the second screen flashed entirely as if it were clicked. So I will attempt to not use a list tile to see if that fixes it. Update: using a normal button still causes the flash, so it's not the list tile causing the problem

Comment: I recommend to add to your `MaterialApp` `showPerformanceOverlay: true`, if it's junky open an issue in flutter's repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frustratingly, it all had to do with the fact that I set the color of the scaffold manually (in the code snippet that color is being set from my main.dart in the theme). If I remove the scaffold coloring, (color was Colors.white30), all of my problems with the routes navigating go away.